# How to get the camera to work with Blackberry Webworks

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am fairly new to webworks. I am trying to get the camera api to work and I keep getting the error:

Error in supported: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'blackberry.media.camera')

The page I am trying to use is on a hosted server. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript" >
function takePicture() {
try {
blackberry.media.camera.takePicture(successCB, closedCB, errorCB);
} catch(e) {
alert("Error in supported: " + e);
}
}
function successCB(filePath) { 
document.getElementById("path").innerHTML = filePath;

//alert("Succeed: " + filePath);
}
function closedCB() {
// alert("Camera closed event");
}
function errorCB(e) {
alert("Error occured: " + e);
}
</script>
<title>Camera Test Widget</title>
</head>
<body >
<p>Test the Camera by pressing the button below</p>
<b><a href="#" onclick="takePicture();">Take a Picture</a></b>
<div id="path"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my config.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" 
version="1.0.0.0" rim:header="WebWorks Sample">
<access uri="http://www.flyloops.net/" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
</access>
<name>Flyloops.net</name>
<description>This is a sample application.</description>
<content src="index.html"/>
</widget>
```

The page is hosted at: http://www.flyloops.net/mobile/bb/camera.html

I have been tearing my hair out for the past 3 hours...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If using PlayBook, make sure to have the correct  element(s) defined
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.media.camera.html

otherwise, if you are trying to access the blackberry.media.camera API *from* a remote website, then you need to white list that correctly in config.xml like this:

```
<access uri="http://www.flyloops.net/" subdomains="true">
   <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
</access>
```

Answer (score 0):

What device are you running?  The code seems fine and it should work.  You can get the eventlogs from the device and see what exceptions are being thrown.

Thanks

Naveen M